# vim - :b partial match mid filename even when matches start of filename

Tags: buffers

In vim, if I have 3 buffers open:

```
test_io
io_fsm
test_mux
```

I want to get to test_io by typing

```
:b io
```

Vim won't list test_io (iterating using tab) as it prefers io_fsm instead.

If I type

```
:b fsm
```

it will list io_fsm as there's no other file starting with fsm.

I'd like the behavior where all matches are listed regardless of whether one of the matches starts with the search term. My only solution now is

```
:b *io
```

Is there a setting I can change to get the behavior I am desiring? I have searched but so far the solution has eluded me.